# symfony2 service container linking / clone service container

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I want to link one service container to another, that is already exist, for example:

```
acme.user.repository:
    class:            '%acme.user.repository.class%'
    arguments:        ['%acme.user.repository.argument%']
    factory_service:  doctrine.orm.entity_manager
    factory_method:   getRepository
```

Now I want to link this service to another, something like this:

```
acme.admin.repository = acme.user.repository
```

So, I will get the same instance when I call `$container->get('acme.admin.repository');` as when I call  `$container->get('acme.user.repository');`

Comment: May I ask you why you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can link your services this way:

```
acme.admin.repository: '@acme.user.repository'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an alias to avoid certain problems:

```
services:

    acme.admin.repository:
        alias: acme.user.repository
```

Comment: Thanks.  I should point out that while both answers may work for your particular use case, there are subtle differences.  For example, ./console container:debug will show aliases but not the first answer.  You may run into issues down the line.

Comment: nice explanation of differences